# Can /etc/rc.local access file in ubuntu encrypted home folder when system startup?

Tags: encryption

My system is Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS

I choose "encrypt home folder" when installing system.

user name is "cm" for example, and I have a program located in /home/cm/Server.

I write "/home/cm/Server &" to /etc/rc.local, but when the system boot  "Server" not start.

Can "/etc/rc.local" access a file in some user's encrypted home folder in boot time?

thanks a lot!

Comment: AFAIK you can't, that's what encryption aught to do! And instead of using `rc.local` use `systemd` so that after opening with key it should run...

Answer (score 0):

No. The whole idea of encrypted home directories is to have the directory be unavailable, unless the user is logged in.

Comment: thanks. I make a experiment , result shows that you are right.